# Selecting UV unwrapping algorithm

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

This website: https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Dev:Source/Textures/UV/Unwrapping/ tells you that there are two algorithms that can be used in Blender to do UV unwrapping.

My question is, how do you actually select manually one particular algorithm from the other?

Comment: This is the old developper wiki from Blender 2.6, it's outdated and it isn't meant for users to begin with.

Comment: @L0Lock https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/uv.html#bpy-ops-uv-unwrap this website also says pretty much the same thing regarding the two unwrapping algorithms. But regardless, could you point me to how can the user select one from the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you do an operation in Blender, you can change its settings in the [Adjust Last Operation panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/undo_redo.html#bpy-ops-screen-redo-last) that shows up in the bottom left corner of the current editor:

[image: last operation]